# SaveAs to document changes in documents loops endlessly

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to force version control in Word documents as our documents are downloaded to work on locally, then re-uploaded.

I had the idea of embedding a macro that runs when a document is closed, presenting an input box, for name/date/summary of changes. This text is added to a hidden bookmark, that can be viewed if there are any version control doubts.

When I share this macro enabled document, saving the file becomes an endless loop. The SaveAs dialog keeps appearing when you click save, and no changes are saved. It works on the system that created the macro.

Reattaching the document template stops this issue, but it would be impractical to expect every user to do this for every document.

Any thoughts on why this save issue occurs, or a more elegant solution?

```vb
Private Sub Document_Close()

Dim MyInput As String
Dim oRng As Word.Range
MyInput = InputBox("Please input your name, the date, and a brief summary of your edits.", "Revision Control", "Name: Date: Summary:")
Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("revcontrol").Range
oRng.Text = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("revcontrol").Range.Text & vbNewLine & MyInput
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "revcontrol", oRng
oRng.Font.Hidden = True
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Just in case: Change `ActiveDocument` which is the document that is on top (has focus) to `ThisDocument` which is the document that code is written in. Note that focus can change by a single mouse click which makes your code unreliable. • How do you proceed when the file is sent to another user. Do you open it from emails directly or do you copy it from emails to the harddisk and then open the file for example? • Also note that using macros is no safe way of version control (if version control is asked for by any legal authority, that will not fullfill the rules).

Comment: Hi PEH,

I have changed the focus as suggested and I believe that has solved the issue! I will have to wait for others to test the file and confirm, but it works between my system and a VM. 

To answer your questions:

The files will always be downloaded to disk and worked on from there.

The macro will also not be used for any legal requirements, My organization creates courseware, and as you have probably experienced, even with naming conventions and processes, occasionally a user will upload a file they believe to be the latest version they have, and it turns out they made an error.

Comment: We have tried using collaborative tools to get around this, such as sharepoint with versioning, but we have found word online to be unstable at keeping the document in the correct format/template. With such strict template and design requirements we cannot afford to have Word changing elements that go unnoticed. This macro will hopefully ensure that users are storing some data about the changes they make, and can compare local files in case of uncertainty.

Comment: Your experience with SharePoint is common, unfortunately. Opening documents directly from email is a recipe for losing work; good practice! The file ends up in a temp folder when opened directly from email. @Peh If you have time, write your suggestions up as an answer, because I believe you have answered the question.

Comment: "found word online to be unstable at keeping the document in the correct format/template" - you can configure your document library to only allow editing in the desktop Word application (since as you note the browser-based editor is unreliable for documents of any real complexity).  Collaborative editing and versioning works well in the desktop app.